# Cannot get spot lights and point lights to illuminate subject in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Im trying to make a BMW logo. I have a white text label with 'BMW' as the text value and Im creating a 3D layer from "New 3D excrusion from selected layer"

Everything seems to function in 3D panel except for the spot lights and point lights. Specifically, I shine these lights on my BMW text and it is not lighting up at all (it makes no difference!) Infinite light (sunlight) however works just fine as expected.

Does anyone possibly know why my spotlights and point lights are not illuminating my text?  Thanks in advance!

Tom P

[image]

Comment: Hi. What version of Photoshop is this?   Did you know that as of version 22.5 (2021), Adobe is discontinuing 3D functionality.  I'm not entirely sure but I believe some of it still works, but if you are using a newer version, chances are that some of these features are no longer fully functional.  Might be better to just jump ship now, and use something like Blender to render your 3D design instead.

Comment: Hi @BillyKerr. I did not know there were phasing out this functionality. My version is 2020 so the functionality is there but Ill take your advice and use a different 3d program or just use layer effects to achive a 3d look. Thanks, man thats very helpful to know!